# Custom MSBuild Task: how to flush logging in VS2012 output window while task is still running?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I have a custom MSBuild task that takes some time to complete. It outputs progress using either `Log.LogMessage()` or `BuildEngine.LogMessageEvent()` (tried both).

My problem is that all output doesn't appear in VS2012 Output window until the task is completed, making progress updates useless. I would like to have output appearing while the task is running, right away.

I found various threads explaining to call frequently `Application.DoEvents()`, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem (maybe it only applied for VS2010 and before?).

Comment: This appears to be a known bug in VS2012 (and I can confirm it also occurs in VS2013) and in usual Microsoft fashsion its status is "can't be bothered to fix". https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/790444/vs2012-msbuild-cant-flush-logging Needless to say, it is incredibly annoying. Did you ever find a workaround?

Comment: In VS2012 we had to VSPackage extension to directly output in pane log.
Seems like VS2015 fixes the issue though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known bug in VS2012.

We ended up making a VSPackage extension for VS2012/2013 (to directly output in pane log).

It is fixed in VS2015.

Comment: I'm using VS2017 and having the same issue. Is there anything that has to be set up for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in VS 2012. In the comments in this [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/790444/vs2012-msbuild-cant-flush-logging) a user whose alias is Will, speaking on behalf of Microsoft, wrote on July the 2nd of 2013 that `Though we will not have a chance to address this issue in Visual Studio 2012, we will consider this feedback when planning for future versions of Visual Studio.`