# Make Log.LogMessage messages appear quickly in VS2013 output window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I have the following C# code in a custom MSBuild task:

```
 Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.High, string.Format("Downloading ROOT v{0}", Version));
 // Do the download
 WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
 webClient.DownloadFile(url, filePath);
```

The `DownloadFile` actually can take a long time. Long enough that if someone doesn't know what is going on they might be tempted to kill the build. Hence the log message I dump on the line before.

When running my build using MSBUILD, this works as expected. The "Downloading ROOT v5.34.20" appears on the console, and then everything pauses for a few minutes while the download occurs.

However, when running in VS2013 the output window remains blank until after the build is finished. Then the proper log lines appear (in the proper order). It looks like MSBUILD's output is being buffered before it is reported to VS2013's output window.

Is there a way to change this behavior? I'd like to cause a flush so that the user knows why their build seems to have paused...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690071/custom-msbuild-task-how-to-flush-logging-in-vs2012-output-window-while-task-is

Comment: Indeed, that does seem to be the same issue.