# Why does msbuild not print immediately messages to Console output window?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I came across on following problem. When I run `msbuild` to buid solution (not project) within pre build event in `visual studio` I see that it prints messages after execution (not immediately). Such behaviour creates illusion that `msbuild` hangs. Is there any way to force it to print messages immediately?

Comment: Build events run with their own Cmd.exe instance.  Without a console, output is redirected.  With the usual consequences of the leaky abstraction of I/O redirection, the build tools you use rarely have the option to use a smaller output buffer or force flushing each line.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Could be related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16690071/2058437